# Upload image from Angular application to a nodejs server using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, multer

The *Angular* application has a form with a file (image) upload that needs to be saved in a folder on the *node.js* server. But for some reason this does not work, the folder where the images should be saved has been created, but the images are not saved there. There are no errors in the console

**My form in *dashboard.component.html* file**

```
<form action="setProfileImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input hidden="true" type="file" name="filedata" id="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
    <label for="file-input">
        <div mat-raised-button class="btn" class="userInfo__addFoto">
            <p>Upload Image</p>
        </div>
    </label>
</form>
```

***dashboard.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile!: File;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filedata',this.selectedFile);
    console.log(formData);
    this.authService.setImage(formData);
  }

}
```

**Function in *auth.service.ts***

```
  setImage(data: any) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/account/setProfileImage',
    data);
  }
```

**Part of the code responsible for this functionality on the *node.js* server**

```
const upload = multer({dest:"uploads"});

router.post('/setProfileImage', upload.single("filedata"), (req, res) => {
    
    filedata = req.file;
 
    console.log(filedata);
    if(!filedata)
        res.send("Ошибка при загрузке файла");
    else
        res.send("Файл загружен");
});
```

Comment: Why are you setting the content-type? I would remove that request header completely

Comment: Already removed but it didn't help

Comment: If you check the request, is it a multipart/form-data?

Comment: have you set express server static assets like below
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/uploads`));